# LaSalle's invariance principle for positive semi definite V

Tags: real-analysis, stability-theory

With $\dot{\textbf{x}}=\dot{\textbf{x}}(\textbf{x})$, if I have a function which has $V(\textbf{x})>0$ when $\textbf{x}\neq \textbf{0}$ for some domain of x, and if $\dot{V}(\textbf{x})\leq 0$ for all $\textbf{x}$, can I somehow apply LaSalle's invariance principle? More specifically, my issue is that my $V(\textbf{x})$ is positive definite in only some variables in $\textbf{x}$, with some other variables in $\textbf{x}$ not being considered.

Comment: You can probably show that $\dot{V} \to 0$. However, if $V$ does not depend on some elements of $x$ then the boundness of $V$ does not necessarily imply the boundness of $x$.

Comment: I mainly want to show that I can still say that we can still say that the system approaches the invariant set where $\dot{V}=0$, not just approaches it.

Comment: The proof of LaSalle that I know is based on the Omega-limit sets. As far as I remember, you need the boundness of trajectories for that. I am unsure if you can use those arguments without showing that the trajectories are bounded.